# Moment last day of month parsing issue

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Why is this not working? I'm going crazy here trying to find where I might have gone wrong but nothing comes to mind. Tested only in Chrome.

```
var startString = "30.01.2017";
var endString = "31.01.2017";

// is OK
var startDate = moment(startString, "DD.MM.YYYY", 'bs',true).clone().toDate();

// breaks down
var endDate = moment(endtString, "DD.MM.YYYY", 'bs',true).clone().toDate();

// console dump
Uncaught ReferenceError: endtString is not defined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Kreiraj:1062)
at j (jquery.js:3094)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:3206)
at Function.ready (jquery.js:3412)
at HTMLDocument.I (jquery.js:3428)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: endString instead of endTString?

Comment: OMG, guess this happens when you have only 2 hours of sleep  .... embarrassing

Comment: Thank you all for being so responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made a Typo. Just change the `endtstring` to `endstring`.

Answer (score 2):

`endtString` is a typo, should be `endString`.